# Using Konovajs with react-native

Tags: react-native, konvajs

How can I use  [konvajs library](https://konvajs.github.io/) with react native. If not, is there any other library which allows defining canvas object declaratively for react native?

Answer (score 1):

React native doesn't use an html5 view, it render native code so you wouldn't be able to use konvasjs, take a look at [react-native-canvas](https://github.com/iddan/react-native-canvas), and see if it fits what you need.